# Force landscape in specific view controller using swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift2

I have app in portrait oriantation for all the view's.

I need to make a landscape for specific views.

I found this.

Put this in the viewDidLoad():

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

and,

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

the problem is that this function only works if I enable landscape right and left mode, and i don't want my app to support landscape.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could mark Landscape Right and Landscape Left, then use `shouldAutorotate` in your views accordingly, but the link below suggests a better method.

I believe this will answer your question: http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/

You can check if the rootViewController contains a "presented controller" and if it does then that class is checked. Thus, if the "check" goes through the UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll (allowing Landscape mode) is returned. If it doesn't then Portrait mode defaults.

I downloaded the sample project in swift and got everything up and running smoothly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: fun application can't return more than 1 !!

Comment: could you describe it for swift 2 !?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your app to support landscape, you can not have a specific view controller forced in landscape, when it loads or whenever you need it.

Comment: are you sure about this !! ,, cuz i see many apps doing this , that's why i ask !